# Delaunay Triangulation on labeled data

Tags: qgis, arcmap, delaunay

I have a table with locations and labeled data and I need to apply Delaunay Triangulation on specific labeled rows.

For example, I have some locations labeled as schools, hostels, gardens, ... and I need to apply triangulation on those specifically labeled items separately.

To solve this I can create as many new tables as labels of interest, but even if I could create such tables it would be daunting task and clearly not very intelligent approach.

Perhaps I could write Python script, but first I thought to ask if there is simpler solution, either in ArcMap or QGIS.